# Adding new property to all angular controls of a certain type

Tags: angular, primeng

We are using PrimeNG's dropdown control in our Angular 14 application.  We'd like to add a property to for Cypress testing.  I could go around to every <p-dropdown control and add the attribute, but I'd prefer to do something like, create a custom control that inherits from Dropdown and takes whatever id we have set on the control and place that value into the attribute.

I've got something like this:

```
    export class DropdownComponent extends Dropdown{
     constructor(el: ElementRef<any>, renderer: Renderer2, cd: ChangeDetectorRef, zone: NgZone, filterService: FilterService, config: PrimeNGConfig)  {
      super(el, renderer, cd, zone, filterService, config);
   }
}
```

And for my template I have something like this:

```
<p-dropdown [attr.data-cy-button]="id">
    
</p-dropdown>
```

My original calling HTML now looks like this:

```
<custom-dropdown
  id="study"
  [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
  [showClear]="true"
  formControlName="study"
  [options]="items | async"
  class="stretch"
  (onChange)="itemChange($event)"
 ></custom-dropdown>
```

However, now that I put my custom component HTML in, my options aren't showing up and I just get an empty dropdown.

I imagine there is some magic to pointing the template to another file but for the life of me I can't find how to wire it up.

How can I basically say, use the template from the base control but add in a few extra attributes so I don't have to add them to all the existing p-dropdown controls?

Comment: The obvious fix to this particular approach is to list all properties so that they're propagated to the PrimeNG component: `<p-dropdown [autoDisplayFirst]="autoDisplayFirst" ...etc`

Comment: @skink I was afraid of that.  I basically wanted the overridden component not to have to recreate the wheel for maintainability's sake.

Comment: However, I'm wondering if it would be easier to write a directive with the `p-dropdown` selector that just modifies the `elementRef.innerHTML` since you're only appending raw HTML attribute. (Hope it's clear what I mean by this description)

Comment: "to all angular controls of a certain type" **Yeah, for this stuff you should use directives**

Answer (score -1):

One possible way would be to get all the `p-dropdown` tags and add the attribute to them with in a simple loop.
Something like this:

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const dropdowns = document.getElementsByTagName('p-dropdown');

    for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; ++i) {
      const dropdown = dropdowns.item(i);
      dropdown.setAttribute('data-cy', dropdown.id + '-for-cypress');
    }
  }
```

Another way extending on previous approach if you don't want to touch the target (Angular) app. Is to trigger a setup before running  tests with `beforeEach`

```
function setupDDLs(doc) {
    console.log('running "DDL setup"');

    const dropdowns = doc.getElementsByTagName('p-dropdown');
    console.log('found [' + dropdowns.length + '] dropdowns');

    for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; ++i) {
      console.log('adding attribute');
      const dropdown = dropdowns.item(i);
      dropdown.setAttribute('data-cy', dropdown.id + '-for-cypress');
    }
}

describe('example to-do app', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit('http://localhost:4200', {
      onLoad: (contentWindow) => {
        setupDDLs(contentWindow.document);
      }
    });
  })

  it('displays two todo items by default', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy=ddl-1-for-cypress]')
      .click();
      
  })
```

HTML:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" id="ddl-1" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity1" placeholder="Select a City" optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
```

Note: This code executes before each test function `it`.